# Filtering the text in SPARQL query based on the language using owlready2

Tags: filter, sparql, lang, owlready

I have an ontology in an 'owl' file (quran_data_full.owl) and I saved it in a folder in my google drive (Quran Corpus). To perform some queries in this ontology, first I tried the query on Apache Jena Fuseki. It gave me the correct results so I copied the query into my code in google collab but unfortunately it gave me an empty set.

This is my code in google collab:

```
from owlready2 import *
onto_path.append("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus")
go = get_ontology("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/quran_data_full.owl").load()
obo = get_namespace("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/")
d = list(default_world.sparql("""
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX qur: <http://quranontology.com/Resource/>
SELECT ?verse ?text 
WHERE {?verse rdf:type qur:Verse.
?verse qur:DiscussTopic ?topic.
?verse rdfs:label ?text.
?topic qur:TopicCompleteName ?topicName.
FILTER (REGEX(STR(?topicName), "زكاة" ,"i")).
FILTER langMatches(lang(?text),"ar")
}
"""))
```

The issue in this line:

```
FILTER langMatches(lang(?text),"ar")
```

When I delete this line it gave me the correct results, however, it gave the text in both Arabic and English, but I want to show only the Arabic text.

[image]

How to filter the text based on the language in owlready2?

This is the result from running the query on Apache Jena Fuseki:

[image]

You can see the full content of quran_data_full.owl file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xLMYASvHkJt1aoVqxG7A7tpbA6RX6nok/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: does it work with `FILTER (lang(?text) = "ar")` instead?

Comment: @UninformedUser No, it gives me this error: OperationalError: no such function: IIF